# Foreach loop not working in modal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach, embed, bootstrap-modal

I have a razor view which displays all pdf files related to a specific user using for each loop. I used `<embed>` to display the pdf file.

```
@foreach (FileInfo res in Model)
{
  <embed src="~/PDF/@res.Name" width="850" height="850" type="application/pdf" />
}
```

Using the code above, it loops and displays the pdf properly. However, I want the pdf to be displayed in modal window. So I have this code below, it loops and displays all the different file names but when I view each, all files display the content of the first file in the modal window.

```
@foreach (FileInfo res in Model)
{
  <div class="modal fade" id="resultmodal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <embed src="~/PDF/@res.Name" width="850" height="850" type="application/pdf" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="#resultmodal" data-toggle="modal">View Result</a>
  </div>
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you change the embed tag source using the res variable inside the loop?

Comment: When debugging in a browsers developer tools,  is it setting each embed src  with distinct file names?

Comment: @ggderas that's the idea, that it should change because it loops

Comment: @QwertyI'm having the same problem with dotnet core. Have you ever found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What if you uniquely handle the event on a each basis by changing `#resultmodal"` to `"#resultmodal@res.Name"` in both the a href view result and the `id="resultmodal@res.Name"` for the modal div?

```
@foreach (FileInfo res in Model)
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="resultmodal@res.Name" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <embed src="~/PDF/@res.Name" width="850" height="850" type="application/pdf" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#resultmodal@res.Name" data-toggle="modal">View Result</a>
    </div>
}
```

That way each view result link is handling a distinct div.

Answer (score 1):

First file is being shown because your every div has id of `resultmodal` and you are targeting `resultmodal` from every `a href`. So it shows the first div found in page. You need to give every div a unique id and also target that div from its respective `a href`'.

```
<div class="modal fade" id=@("#resultmodal" +res.Name) role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-body">
       <embed src="~/PDF/@res.Name" width="850" height="850" type="application/pdf" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href=@("#resultmodal" +res.Name) data-toggle="modal">View Result</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, tried this but it does not even show the modal window.

Comment: Div ids which are made by `id=@("#resultmodal" +res.Name)`

Comment: When I click the "View Result", I did not see the id in the url it's just "#"

Comment: ok you can decalre a variable of type `int` and  bind it with `@("#resultmodal" +FileNo)` and increment it with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Mairaj Ahmad does work, but there is a single # that needs to be removed from the first div id. So the code will be as follow:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id=@("resultmodal" +res.Name) role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-body">
       <embed src="~/PDF/@res.Name" width="850" height="850" type="application/pdf" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href=@("#resultmodal" +res.Name) data-toggle="modal">View Result</a>
</div>
```